# Could not find method intTestImplementation() for arguments [org.hibernate:hibernate:5.3.7.FINAL] on object of type DefaultDependencyHandler

Tags: gradle

I am trying to configure the Integration tests in Gradle 5.0.

I am seeing error as

```
Could not find method intTestImplementation() for arguments [org.hibernate:hibernate:5.3.7.FINAL] on object of type DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

I can see the `intTestImplementation` when I say `gradle dependencies`

I am trying to add one dependency

`intTestImplementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate:5.3.7.FINAL'`

```
task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    description = 'Runs integration tests.'
    group = 'verification'

    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.intTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.intTest.runtimeClasspath
    shouldRunAfter test
}

sourceSets {
    intTest {
        java.srcDir file('src/integrationTest/java')
        resources.srcDir file('src/integrationTest/resources') // to add the resources
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try one of these two options and see if some of them works for you:

**a) your custom `sourceSets` declared in this way:**

> ```
> sourceSets {
>     intTest {
>         java {
>             srcDirs = ['src/integrationTest/java']
>         }
>         resources {
>             srcDirs = ['src/integrationTest/resources']
>         }
>         compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.main.compileClasspath + sourceSets.test.compileClasspath
>         runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath + sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
>      } 
> }
> ```

In this case you would be declaring your dependencies for integration tests in the same way as the dependencies for tests. Just like this:

> ```
> testImplementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate:5.3.7.FINAL'
> ```

**b) `intTestImplementation` must be declared after your custom `sourceSets`:**

> ```
> sourceSets {
>     intTest {
>         java {
>             srcDirs = ['src/integrationTest/java']
>         }
>         resources {
>             srcDirs = ['src/integrationTest/resources']
>         }
>      } 
>  }
> dependencies {
>     intTestImplementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate:5.3.7.FINAL'
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I got similar message because I had my `sourceSets` defined after `dependencies`